# How can I dump a MySQL database without using mysqldump in Python

Tags: python, mysql

How can I dump a MySQL database without using mysqldump, just by using Python including table structure?

Comment: Why without mysqldump? Making a system call to `mysqldump` is going to be the easiest method by far.

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is a "how can I make my problem needlessly difficult" question.

Comment: I want my app portable with very little dependencies. My reason not use MySQLdump

Comment: But you already have a dependency on MySQL which means you have the `mysqldump` tool at your disposal.

Comment: @donturner MySQL install on a remote host.

Comment: @SamuelTaylor Consider adding that information into your question next time, you will get better answers if you put more effort in.

Comment: I cannot use `mysqldump` with my provider, but I can use SQL queries. I think this question is interesting and should be re-opened.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly valid question. I've encountered several hosters which use different (dedicated) servers for web applications and databases. In these cases mysqldump is not available on the web application server and can not be used for backup purposes.

Comment: I'm with @Ole on this one.  Imagine you want to dump a database using an AWS Lambda function (where the AMI does not include mysqlclient tools.)

Comment: StackOverflow being unnecessarily restrictive once again. This is a perfectly valid question because there are genuine situations where this is warranted. Sometimes the Python environment is set up in such a way that it does not have access to the binary executables of mysql but the library does have it. Which means we have to look at workarounds.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import datetime

con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', db='test')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SHOW TABLES")
data = ""
tables = []
for table in cur.fetchall():
    tables.append(table[0])

for table in tables:
    data += "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + str(table) + "`;"

    cur.execute("SHOW CREATE TABLE `" + str(table) + "`;")
    data += "\n" + str(cur.fetchone()[1]) + ";\n\n"

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM `" + str(table) + "`;")
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data += "INSERT INTO `" + str(table) + "` VALUES("
        first = True
        for field in row:
            if not first:
                data += ', '
            data += '"' + str(field) + '"'
            first = False


        data += ");\n"
    data += "\n\n"

now = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = str(os.getenv("HOME")) + "/backup_" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M") + ".sql"

FILE = open(filename,"w")
FILE.writelines(data)
FILE.close()
```

Seem to work well from a little testing.

Comment: Please note that `pymysql` is an alternative to `MySQLdb` which is pure Python and works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.X.

Comment: Its a good effort but sad part is, MySQLdb doesnt provides a call for dumping database instead we will have to execute query and get reponse which needed to be append manually into a file which is just the long way around

Comment: Just to add: You can save some system memory by writing straight to file, rather than appending to the `data` variable. ex: `FILE.write("DROP TABLE...`

Comment: Makes sense @Aron

Comment: Is this ignoring foreign key/constraints  and other information about the database?

Answer (score 4):

I would advise [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) - it provides a MySQL API for Python.

However, most probably the API does an indirect call to `mysqldump`. You don't want to call `mysqldump` directly or at all?

You might also want to check out [Dump tables and data](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/24635-dump-table-data-mysqldb) where the exact procedure to dump the table structure and data (down the page) without MySQLdb is shown.