# Export an AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL database with mysqldump

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

Is it possible to export an AWS Aurora Serverless MySQL database with mysqldump without using an EC2 instance?

Comment: Fargate can be the best option as lambda has max execution time which can break the functionally for large database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to emulate *mysqldump* using *Python* and the *AWS Data API*.

To emulate *mysqldump*, I followed:

[How can I dump a MySQL database without using mysqldump in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534087/how-can-i-dump-a-mysql-database-without-using-mysqldump-in-python)

Comment: Could you share your code doing dump by Data API?

Answer (score 2):

At this time you cannot gain public access to Aurora, or use a site to site VPN connection to connect to it.

Whichever resource you use will need to reside within the VPC of the Aurora Serverless cluster. Possible solutions to bypass the requirement for EC2 would be either running a Fargate container to run your command or looking at Lambda to execute the command.

Comment: You are right, I need to edit the question because I'd rather not use an EC2 instance.

Comment: Great! I'm working on a Python Lambda script right now. Do you know any example?

Comment: Theres a few examples online such as https://jake-webber.com/2019-06-09-backup-mysql-with-aws-lambda.html or https://jarombek.com/blog/sep-5-2019-rds-backups-pt2. :)